# ¿Por qué los autobuses de los aeropuertos se llaman "jardineras"?

Tags: etimología, transporte

Después de aterrizar mi avión en Barcelona, he tenido que ir en "jardinera" hasta la terminal. En ese momento se me ha ocurrido pensar que el nombre de "jardinera" para llamar a un autobús que circula por dentro del aeropuerto es realmente curioso y me ha surgido la pregunta sobre su origen.

Este [artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jardinera_(carruaje)) explica, por lo que parece basándose en el contenido del *Diccionario Enciclopédico Hispano-Americano* del año 1898, que una "jardinera" es (o era) un cierto tipo de

> carruaje abierto de cuatro ruedas utilizado para el campo

y que también se llama "jardinera"

> al vehículo utilizado en los aeropuertos para transportar a los viajeros entre la terminal y el avión.

Sin embargo, no menciona cuál es el origen de este nombre. Estas definiciones están también recogidas en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/jardinero).

Buscando con Google, he encontrado este [blog](https://blogs.lavozdegalicia.es/mundoexotico/2011/06/21/koh-samui-tailandia-%C2%BFpor-que-se-les-llama-jardineras-a-los-autobuses-del-aeropuerto/) en el que se puede leer esto:

> Como este autobús, se parece más a una jardinera para mover tiestos que a un autobús, así se les ha llamado y este es el nombre con el que todo el mundo las denomina, “Jardineras”.

No me parece una explicación demasiado convincente y esta es la razón por la que hago esta pregunta: ¿por qué se llama "jardinera" a este tipo de autobús?

---

**Actualización:**

Como algunos comentarios parecen sugerir que se trata de un vocablo que se usa poco o que es de uso regional dentro de España, pongo aquí un par de ejemplos de utilización  de "jardinera" con este significado provenientes de artículos del diario *El País* ([1](https://elpais.com/ccaa/2013/10/09/madrid/1381355817_282876.html) y [2](https://elpais.com/elpais/2007/08/28/actualidad/1188289018_850215.html), negrita mía):

> "No es casual que Ryanair, Easyjet o Vueling [el convenio de sus pilotos limita además los vuelos en Madrid y los favorece en El Prat] lideren las operaciones en Barcelona, que se ha convertido en el *hub* de bajo coste de España. El *handling*, que tiene una duración media de una hora, se puede hacer de dos maneras: o en *remoto*, es decir, trasladando a los pasajeros en ***jardinera*** hasta el aparato o la terminal, más económico y la opción predilecta de las *low cost*, o bien mediante el *finger*, más cómodo, rápido... Y caro. Ninguna sale rentable en Madrid”, observan voces autorizadas.

> Ante esta situación, los pasajeros decidieron sentarse al lado de su avión, aparcado en una de las plataformas del aeródromo barcelonés, hasta que no se les diese una solución. 
>   Los vehículos de Aena y las llamadas **jardineras** rodearon a los pasajeros para que no se alejaran del aparato.

Comment: Depende de la región, es la primera vez que lo oigo, jamás en Madrid o Valladolid

Comment: Nunca lo he oído en Colombia. Aqui se llaman "bus". La definición del DLE no menciona una región en la que se use pero me pienso que su uso no es general.

Comment: Soy de barcelona y jamas escuche el termino jardinera para hablar de los buses. Los autobuses del aeropuerto son conocidos como "Lanzadera". Se les llama así porque tienen un recorrido de ida y vuelta constante, parecido a la lanzadera de los telares

Comment: @Aimnox: Yo también soy de Barcelona y sí que los llamo "jardineras" y he oído a otras personas llamarlos así.

Answer (score 2):

Historia del transporte metropolitano en la ciudad de Las Palmas de Gran Canaria: desde 1929 hasta 1986, la empresa municipal se llamó Jardineras Guaguas y en su web explican el origen de este nombre y su uso en el nombre de nuestras guaguas (autobuses).
[image: capturade la web de Guaguas Municipales de LasPalmasdeGranCanaria.]

Answer (score 1):

Parece que originalmente una "[jardinera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jardinera_(carruaje))" es un vehículo para transportar utensilios de campo y jardinería.

Algunos modelos tienen *caja* para llevar tiestos o macetas, con un toldo bastante alto para que quepan plantas o arbolitos:

[image: jardinera de jardín]

Lo que distingue a las lanzaderas de aeropuerto de autobuses convencionales es que los primeros no suelen tener asientos, o si tienen son pocos. Es fácil imaginar la comparación entre una jardinera y un autobús sin asientos, que en la parte de carga en lugar de arbolitos en macetas lleva pasajeros de pie:

[image: jardinera de aeropuerto]