# Let's take a relay bus ride through the world! What are some regional terms for 'bus' in Spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, transporte

Inspired by a recent question about *jardineras* ([¿Por qué los autobuses de los aeropuertos se llaman "jardineras"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32610/9385)):

**Let's have a parade of buses** from different regions.  Add your favorite words for rail-less public transportation -- images welcome! (But let's try to use *small* images.)

Comment: I cannot agree with the edits that rollbacked my suggestions (https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/32723/revisions). Questions are questions, not an introduction to the answers. Most of the wording here is meta stuff that does not add any value to future readers. We have to think in the readers of the question, not in the editors: the call to edit or improve is implicit by having a wiki answer

Comment: @fedorqui - I don't mind if you want to restore your title.  I wanted to have some fun.  (Such sad things happening with SE.)  But I can still have some fun with this question even if you take the fun out of the title.  And you have more experience with SE than I do.

Comment: I'm not going to rollback a rollback, I mentioned the case here to prevent such wars and express what I think is best for the question

Answer (score 6):

#### Argentina

- [colectivo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=colectivo) (dentro de las ciudades)
- [micro](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=micro), [ómnibus](http://ttps://dle.rae.es/%C3%B3mnibus) (de media o larga distancia)
- micro escolar

#### Bolivia

- Flota, bus grande interurbano, para más de 30 personas, donde los posibles asientos de lujo son "leito" por contaminación lingüistica brasilera (algo justificado, ya que brasil tiene las fábricas de buses sudamericanos).
- Micro, bus chico urbano o rural (usualmente para menos de 30 pasajeros).
- Combi, similar a Perú, en el lado de las tierras altas, y además se conoce el
- [Trufi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiva_(veh%C3%ADculo)), que puede ser cualquier vehículo entre el Toyota [Ipsum](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=guagua) y el  [Noah](https://dle.rae.es/?w=camioneta). Estos pueden circular por una ruta establecida dentro de la ciudad como también pueden recorrer entre ciudades.

#### Chile

- Bus es el nombre en general para los vehiculos desde
  "la liebre", o "la micro", que puede variar entre un [Mitsubishi Rosa](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=colectivo) o la micro rural clásica [Mercedes](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=micro) y usualmente se usa ruralmente para recorridos de menos de dos horas, y el bus de dos pisos, para viajes interurbanos, que puede contener asientos reclinables "Salon Cama". El tacaño o simplemente económico siempre viaja "ejecutivo" o "clásico".
- Micro, que vale actualmente cerca de $400CLP tarifa fija, se le llama "la micro" seguido del numero de la ruta: "Toma la micro 1B hasta Santiago Rosas con calle Las Moras." Acostumbraban ser típicas las infames [micros amarillas](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=kkBkAhQaJx0Afq6b8lr) de Santiago, pero se han ido mejorando, y a la fecha (2020) son bastante modernos.
- Transfer, transporte del hotel al aeropuerto (prestado del inglés, seguro) "Transfer" (tipo Hyundai H1 o Peugot [Expert](http://ttps://dle.rae.es/%C3%B3mnibus)

#### Colombia

- Bus
- [buseta](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=kkBkAhQaJx0Afq6b8lr) Vehículo de transporte público de menor tamaño que el bus
- [chiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiva_(veh%C3%ADculo)) Transporte rural consistente en un chasis de camión y bancas de madera

#### Cuba

- [guagua](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=guagua)

#### Ecuador

- [chiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiva_(veh%C3%ADculo)) (transporte rural consistente en un chasis de camion y bancas de madera)

#### España

- autobús (uso general)
- [camioneta](https://dle.rae.es/?w=camioneta) (*coloq*. Autobús que presta sus servicios en algunos barrios).
- [guagua](https://dle.rae.es/?w=guagua) (Canarias)
- lanzadera, [jardinera](https://dle.rae.es/jardinero) (traslados específicos, por ej. de avión a terminal)

#### México

- autobús (larga distancia: primera o segunda clase)
- [camión](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cami%C3%B3n) (para referirse al autobús escolar)
- totolera (hace muchas paradas; permiten gallinas, [totoles](https://dle.rae.es/totol) (guajolotes), etc.)

  [image: La totolera cerámica]
  ([fuente de la imagen](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/funny-vintage-mexico-pottery-rustic-474511281))
- urbano, combi, colectivo (urbano o rural)

#### Panamá

- [chiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiva_(veh%C3%ADculo)) (transporte rural consistente en un chasis de camion y bancas de madera)

#### Peru

- bus, people understand this but is uncommon usually larger buses
- combi, medium or small buses basically different models resembling [Volkswagen Type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Type_2#/media/File:0385_Porsche_Diesel_Bus_blau.jpg)
- micro, usually larger and especially related with old buses

#### Uruguay

- Bondi (Montevideo)
- Omnibús (el interior del país)

Comment: guagua en Canarias también y en México usan camión al menos para el bus escolar

Comment: Soy de España y no conocía lo de "jardinera". Siempre he usado el término "lanzadera" para un servicio de autobús entre dos puntos específicos.

Comment: @Spuny En Chile esos se llaman (prestado, seguro) "transfer"; usualmente son un furgoncito tipo Hyundai H1. Un hotel puede publicar "servicio transfer aeropuerto", por ejemplo, y hay empresas dedicadas al servicio.

Comment: in Peru you can use "Micro", "Bus" or "Combi". usually are generic but also it depends on the bus size you can use:
Micro is usually larger and specially old buses 
Bus, people understand this but is uncommon 
Combi is medium or small buses basically differente models resembling  Volkswagen Type 2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Type_2#/media/File:0385_Porsche_Diesel_Bus_blau.jpg)

Comment: @Grubhart - Dive in and edit the community wiki answer -- that's great information.

Comment: @Conrado - ditto!

Comment: The qualification “para transporte dentro de la ciudad” for the _colectivo_ doesn’t seem appropriate to me (at least for Mexico). At least, the colectivos I’ve taken in Mexico have all been in very rural areas. I see the description was originally added for _urbano_ and the others were added later – was it supposed to only qualify that one?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Which term is commonly used varies from one city to another.  In fact, some cities just don't have any of these vans or mini-buses at all.  In some, the middle class uses them whenever possible, instead of a city bus.  Mexico is not homogeneous in its transportation solutions.

Comment: @aparente001 My point was that _colectivos_ are not specifically urban the way they’re described here. I imagine _urbanos_ are indeed specifically urban, based on the name, and I don’t know about _combis_, but specifying _colectivos_ as urban implies they don’t exist outside cities, which they do.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Oh, okay, that has a simple solution.  The answer is community wiki, so you can edit it freely and make any corrections you feel are needed, for example, you can make a new entry, or you can edit what's in the parentheses descriptions. // The ones you took in rural areas -- were they just medium distance, or also long distance?  And out of curiosity, were animals permitted?

Comment: @aparente001 I didn’t want to make an incorrect edit since I’m not familiar with the other two types – wasn’t sure what to separate out and what to keep together. I’d say the ones I took were medium distance – about five to ten miles or so, perhaps a bit more. I took one from San Pedro Puchutla to Zipolite, for instance. I don’t know if animals would have been permitted – there weren’t any that I recall, but there could perhaps have been.

Comment: Oye, @aparente001, I meant to add to the wiki but mistakenly created a new answer...? I'm sorry.

Comment: @Conrado - No worries, just copy your material (easiest way is to edit your answer and copy the source code, so to speak), and then add it to the wiki by clicking edit on that.  If you don't mind.  Otherwise you might start a trend and then we'll have a big mess.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - check my edit, please.  I used Conrado's wording (urbano o rural).  I think that "rural" exactly captures what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Agarré hace poquito un *combi* al centro de Morelia desde la central de autobuses.

También quería notar nomás que *camión* se usa en México más generalmente, no sólo para el autobús escolar.