# Is 'colectivo' the most appropriate translation for bus?

Tags: traducción, transporte

If I want to refer to a bus, would I use the term 'colectivo' or 'autobús'? I assume it would depend on where I am. Is 'colectivo' more appropriate in South America or Spain?

I guess that 'colectivo' is a reference to a collection of people in a bus as oppose to one or two which might be more of a car than a bus.

Comment: Bus comes from Latin omnibus, meaning “for all”, “for everybody”. “Colectivo” conveys that meaning.

Comment: Related: [Let's take a relay bus ride through the world! What are some regional terms for 'bus' in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32723/1674)

Comment: First time I heard _colectivo_ (used for bus). In Spain, we say _autobús_ or simply _bus_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Colectivo* is the most common term to refer to an urban bus in Argentina, and a common term for buses of different kinds in Paraguay, Ecuador and Venezuela. (For more details see the Wikipedia article *[autobús](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autob%C3%BAs)*.) In Argentina *colectivo* specifically means "urban bus" in Buenos Aires, while *micro* is used for the long-distance buses. In other parts of the country *colectivo* is used for both types.

*Bus*, *autobús* and *ómnibus* should be understood everywhere, but the preferences vary. In some countries there seem to be half a dozen or more modes of mass public transportation on roads, each with its own particular name.

Comment: In Dominican Republic we say guagua for a bus. The bus service in the capital is referred to as "la omsa" (Oficina Metropolitana de Servicios de Autobuses). It's common to say something like, "Voy a tomar una omsa."

Answer (score 5):

Pablo's answer is right, I'll just add that in Chile, "la micro" (unlike Buenos Aires where it's "el micro") is an urban bus, "bus" is a long-distance bus, and "colectivo" is some weird kind of taxi that has some more or less predefined route and is shared by up to 4 passangers (and if there are less than 4, they'll just wait there until more people arrive).

Trust me, asking for the colectivo there will be confusing for everybody!

Comment: In Mexico a *colectivo* is similar to what is described here, a van which takes around 4 - 8 people along a somewhat flexible predefined route. A city bus or inter-city bus is a *camión*.

Answer (score 2):

A small remark to add to the previous answers. It is an interesting word, since as you probably know, *bus* is the abbreviation of Latin *omnibus* "for all", dative plural of *omnis* "all". So *colectivo* is actually a direct translation of *omnibus*, but it is only used in S. America, whereas the original Latin *omnibus* or *bus*, are used everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pablo's answer. Bus, autobús and ómnibus should are widely understood.

Only use local terminology or slang if you're definitely sure your target audience will be "in-the-know."